# Check the base change is a homeomorphism locally

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is a proposition in Gortz-Wedhorn's book about fiber product of schemes and base change.

[image]

In the proof, it says that if $f$ satisfies assumption (I), then all assertions can be checked locally on $S$, $Y$ and $X$. What confused me is the part that $g$ is a homeomorphism onto $g(Z')$. I don't understand why we can check it locally here. If we cover $X$, $Y$ and $S$ by open coverings and assume that we can prove that it holds for these coverings, i.e. we have a morphism in this form $$g: \bigcup X_{ij}'\times_{S_i}Y_{ik} \to \bigcup X_{ij}\times_{S_i}Y_{ik}$$ and each restriction $$X_{ij}'\times_{S_i}Y_{ik} \to X_{ij}\times_{S_i}Y_{ik}$$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. But homeomorphisms doesn't glue to a homeomorphism necessarily. If we can prove that $g$ is injective, I think it will become much easier. But "injective", "homeomorphism" are not stable under base change in general.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I've figured it out now. (I) means that $f$ is a monomorphism, which is stable under base change, i.e. $g$ is a monomorphism.